# Tweepy Error: Request exceeds account’s current package request limits

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I'm using the Tweepy API to collect tweets containing specific keywords or hashtags through the standard Academic Research Developer Account. This allows me to collect 10,000,000 tweets per month. I'm trying to collect the tweets from one full calendar date at a time using the full archive search. I've gotten a rate limit error (despite the wait_on_rate_limit flag being set to true) and now this request limit error. I'm not totally sure why or what to change at this point?

```
consumer_key = '***'
consumer_secret = '***'
access_token = '***'
access_token_secret = '***'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

def get_tweets_withHashTags(query, startdate, enddate, count = 300):
    tweets_hlist= []
    tweets_list= []
    qt=str(query) 
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive, label='myLabel', query=qt, fromDate=startdate+'0000',toDate=enddate+'0000',maxResults=100).pages(100):
      count = len(page)
      print( "Count of tweets in each page for  " + str(qt) + " : " +  str(count))
      for value in page:
        hashList = value._json["entities"]["hashtags"]
        flag = 0
        for tag in hashList:
            if qt.lower() in tag["text"].lower():
                flag = 1

        if flag==1:
          tweets_hlist.append(value._json)
        tweets_list.append(value._json)

    print("tweets_hash_"+ query +": " + str(len(tweets_hlist)))
    print("tweets_"+ query +": " + str(len(tweets_list)))
    
    with open("/Users/Victor/Documents/tweetCollection/data/"+startdate +"/" + "query1_hash_" + str(startdate)+ "_" + str(enddate) + "_" +query+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(tweets_hlist, outfile, indent = 2)

    with open("/Users/Victor/Documents/tweetCollection/data/"+startdate +"/"+"query1_Contains_" + str(startdate)+ "_" + str(enddate) + "_" +query+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(tweets_list, outfile, indent = 2)
    return len(tweets_list)

query = ["keyword1","keyword2","keyword3", etc. ]
for value in query:
  get_tweets_withHashTags(value,"20200422","20200423")
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer, Tweepy does not support version 2 of the Twitter API (although there is a [Pull Request to add initial support](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1535)). The `api.search_full_archive` is actually hitting the v1.1 Premium Full Archive search, which has a lower request and Tweet cap volume limit, so that is why you are seeing an error about exceeding your package.

For the Full Archive / All Tweets endpoint in v2 of the API, you need a Project in the Academic Track, and an App in that Project. You'll need to point your code at the `/2/tweets/search/all` endpoint. If you are using Python, there is [sample code in the TwitterDev repo](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Full-Archive-Search/full-archive-search.py). This uses the requests library, rather than using a full API library like Tweepy.

Comment: Thanks, I used the sample code and modified it for my searches but when I run it I'm getting "ImportError: No module named requests"
I looked into it and did "easy_install twitter" like some people recommended but that didn't fix it either. I think I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Check the readme, you need to `pip install requests` and `pip install requests-oauthlib`